# Use of resistors on signal lines of serial to parallel shift register

Tags: voltage, resistors, integrated-circuit, current-limiting, shift-register

I have recently come across a circuit with a serial to parallel shift register(HEF4094B), and Vcc 12V. I could see that resistors are connected in series to the signal pins(OE, STR, DATA, CP).

- 2.2kΩ to STR
- 2.2KΩ to DATA
- 2.2kΩ to CP
- 1kΩ to OE

I failed to understand the role of resistors here, are they being connected to limit the current ? but, in that case, would those resistors not drop the voltage required by the signal pins.

Please help me understand the role of resistors here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The resistors won't drop any voltage because there's no current through them (the 4094B input pins have very high impedance). The pins do have a small capacitance so with the resistor a small delay is introduced. That could be used to fix a setup or hold violation between DATA and DP, but since those resistors are the same value that's not the case here - no point delaying them the same amount. Maybe the driving signals come from  some source greater than 12V? Then the resistors would serve as a current limiter. Might be being used to damp out overshoot.

Comment: Post the schematic or all you'll get is random guesses.